# How to create pie chart in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pie-chart

I want to show pie chart of my category by percentage.

How can I create pie chart of category percentage ?

Comment: you can refer my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231244/draw-pie-chart-using-ios-quartz-2d/30004287#30004287 which just includes a single line of code to draw pie chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is API by that you can do this thing.

1. [MIMChart](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/08/iphoneipad-chart-librarymimchartlib.html)
2. [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) Effective but not handy library.

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement a class which overrides the `drawRect:` method and draw the pie yourself. You'd use [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) class, specifically look into the [addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addArcWithCenter%3aradius%3astartAngle%3aendAngle%3aclockwise%3a) method to draw a part of a circle.

See also [this article](http://rajeev.name/2009/01/18/drawing-pie-charts-using-iphone-sdk/) and [this article](http://www.tempura.org/rants/2010/07/pie-charts-on-ios/).

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful with the warning that if it looks like someone else's code, it's because I worked out how to do it with web sites, and the additional warning that I did this not long after starting iPhone. People who want to tell me which bits are inefficient or wrong are welcome, I'm still learning.

```
static inline float radians(double degrees) { return degrees * M_PI / 180; }

// making a simple pac man shape
- (UIImage*)getImage {

    UIImage* image;
    if(self.completion == 100.0f) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"completedTaskIcon.png"];
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(SIDELENGTH, SIDELENGTH));

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // the image should have a clear background
        [[UIColor clearColor] set];
        CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, SIDELENGTH, SIDELENGTH);
        UIRectFill(myRect);

        // color was hopefully set before this method called
        [self.color set];

        // centre point is required
        CGFloat midx = SIDELENGTH/2;
        CGFloat midy = SIDELENGTH/2;
        // radius of the arc
        CGFloat radius = (SIDELENGTH/2) * 0.60f;

        // pie background
        CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]));
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midx + radius, midy);
        CGContextAddArc(context, midx, midy, radius,  radians(0), radians(360), 0); 
        CGContextFillPath(context); 

        // pie segment
        CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]));
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midx, midy);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, midx + radius, midy);
        CGContextAddArc(context, midx, midy, radius,  radians(0), radians(360 * (self.completion / 100.0f)), 0); 
        CGContextFillPath(context); 
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the proposed library in the other answers, there are two really good open source pie chart classes that I used. They look very nice, are extremely simple, have a look at them at GitHub:

- [XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart)
- [NBPieChart](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty)