# Requirements to generate Piechart dynamically

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create pie chart in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766766/how-to-create-pie-chart-in-iphone)

Any external sources required to generate the Pie-Chart to the application as per the percentage came in the parsing (like 35%, 15%, 30%, 20% etc...). See the reference i am attacing here...

[image]

How can i begin with the code to create & display the dynamic PieChart in application?

It should be dynamic as per the URL Tag's value.

Thanks for every suggestions & guidance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a whole host of solutions to your problem by googling it. Here are a few useful sources to look at:

http://rajeev.name/2009/01/18/drawing-pie-charts-using-iphone-sdk/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkS6HOuHaBM