# draw pie chart using iOS quartz 2D

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-2d, pie-chart

I am looking for a tutorial where I can draw pie chart programmatically using Core Graphics or Quartz 2D in iOS. I want to understand how can we draw the PIE Chart which is gradient and having multi-color filled slices in it.

Note: Not looking for Coreplot framework.

Please share me some links regarding the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used "XYPieChart" library in my so many apps and it's very easy to modify.

Available on github.

Link is given below:

https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart

Still needs any help then let me know.

Comment: Hi This looks cool and is there any tutorial or similar sample code for Line and Bar Charts ?

Comment: This code is the simplest code I have found. It is very easy to use. Try to explore this code more as this library contains both charts.

Comment: Very nice.  It's not a heavy framework, just a simple control with delegates.  No harder to implement than a UITableView.  Nice find.

Comment: Anyone know how to properly center the pie chart? I've setup the layout constraints in IB on my xib but it seems like the pie itself doesn't adhere to it. i'm trying to setPieCenter to the center point of the view that contains the pie view but i can't get it to go where i want.

Comment: In XIB you can put PieChart View in center. It's really easy to do.

Comment: ok i now realize that the pie is always drawn center to the pieChart.frame rectangle. so i can set the pie's initial frame to its parent content frame and the pie will be in the middle. if i need to change the frame, i can then use setPieCenter to change the position of the pie within its frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this library](https://github.com/rajatdeep/iOS-PieChartDemo), as this is also completely customisable and too easy to use.

Just use one line of code, this method along with the pie chart view used & the array with values to be rendered in the pie chart view:

```
- (void)renderInLayer:(RJPieChart *)layerHostingView dataArray:(NSMutableArray*)dataArray
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks